# I need this matching method to skip over blank cells and not include them as a matched value

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, match, matching

This code works almost perfectly. The problem is it includes blank cells in its "matched" results. What do I need to change to make this code ignore blank cells? Below I will include an example of what is going on.

[image]

```
Sub MarkMatches()
    Const TopLeftCell As String = "A2"      ' change to match where your data are

    Dim Rng As Range                        ' data range
    Dim FirstRow As Long, FirstClm As Long
    Dim Data As Variant                     ' original data (2-D)
    Dim Arr As Variant                      ' data rearranged (1-D)
    Dim Tmp As Variant                      ' working variable
    Dim R As Long, R1 As Long               ' row counters
    Dim C As Long                           ' column counter
    Dim Count() As String                   ' match counter

    With Range(TopLeftCell)
        FirstRow = .Row
        FirstClm = .Column
    End With
    C = Cells(FirstRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstClm), _
                    Cells(Rows.Count, FirstClm).End(xlUp).Offset(0, C - FirstClm))
    Data = Rng.Value

    ReDim Arr(1 To UBound(Data))
    For R = 1 To UBound(Data)
        ReDim Tmp(1 To UBound(Data, 2))
        For C = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Tmp(C) = Data(R, C)
        Next C
        Arr(R) = Tmp
    Next R

    ReDim Count(1 To UBound(Arr))
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr) - 1
        For R1 = R + 1 To UBound(Arr)
            Tmp = 0
            For C = 1 To UBound(Arr(R))
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(Arr(R)(C), Arr(R1), 0)) Then
                    Tmp = Tmp + 1
                End If
            Next C
            If Tmp > 0 Then                 ' change to suit
                Tmp = Format(Tmp, "(0)") & ", "
                Count(R) = Count(R) & CStr(R1 + FirstRow - 1) & Tmp
                Count(R1) = Count(R1) & CStr(R + FirstRow - 1) & Tmp
            End If
        Next R1
    Next R

    For R = 1 To UBound(Count)
        If Len(Count(R)) Then Count(R) = Left(Count(R), Len(Count(R)) - 2)
    Next R
    ' set the output column here (2 columns right of the last data column)
    '   to avoid including this column in the evaluation
    '   it must be blank before a re-run
    Set Rng = Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(0, UBound(Data, 2) + 1)
    Rng.Value = Application.Transpose(Count)
End Sub
```

Thank you @Variatus for the code and help so far!

Comment: The photo provided is the output of the macro. The original data resides in A1:F6.

Comment: Nothing should be different in the output other than excluding the "matched" results from blank cells. The first row of output should be empty. It currently is not because the code includes blank cells in matched results.

Comment: Anyone there???

Comment: What does your output represent?  When I run your code using your input data (A1:D6), I'm not getting that same output. If there are values (blank spaces?) in columns E and F, that's not clear.  You `Application.Match` statement is not working at all, by the way. It expects a `Range` for the second parameter and you're giving it a value.

Comment: The input data is A1:F6. The output data is displayed in column H. For example the last row of output data says “3(2)” which means that there is 2 matches with row 3 in that row (row 6).  Column E and F are blank. Column G is not used and simply used as a division between the input and output data. The problem is that my current code includes matching blank cells. I would be very thankful if someone could help me fix this to make it where the blank cells are simply ignored. If there is anything else you are unsure about please let me know, thank you!

Comment: So you're wanting to identify each unique item and note which row it's on (ignoring blanks). Then produce a row-by-row report (in column H) showing other rows that have duplicate values to the values in that row (ignoring blanks)?

Comment: YES PLEASE!!!!!!!! Any more questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to work with your original code, but honestly I became very confused. My example below will illustrate some practices that could help (and those who may review your code later, including yourself!). So here's a list of comments:

1. [Always use `Option Explicit`](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html). Your code may already have this, but I'm listing it here for completeness sake.
2. Create variable names that describe what data it holds. Your code does a little of this, but some of the variable names are difficult to fit into the logic flow. My idea in coding is always to try and write self-documenting code. That way, it's nearly always clear what the code is trying to accomplish. Then I'll use comment for code blocks where it might be a bit less clear. (Don't fall into the trap of prefixing variable names with a "type" or something; it's ultimately not worth it.)
3. A clear description of the problem always helps. This is true not only to get help on SO, but also for yourself. My final comment to your post above, asking about the problem description really simplified everything. This includes describing what you want your output to show.

As per the problem description, you need to identify each unique item and keep track of which row you find that item so you can create a report later. A `Dictionary` is a perfect tool for this. [Read up about how to use a `Dictionary`](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/), but you should be able to follow what this block of code is doing here (even without all the previous declarations):

```
    For Each cell In dataArea.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If items.Exists(cell.Value) Then
                '--- add this row to the list
                rowList = items(cell.Value) & "," & cell.Row
                items(cell.Value) = rowList
            Else
                '--- first time adding this value
                items.Add cell.Value, cell.Row
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
```

It's easy to see how the logic of this code follows the description of the problem. After that, it's just a matter of running through each row in the data area and checking each value on that row to see if duplicates exist on any other row. The full example solution is below for you to study and adjust to fit your situation.

```
Option Explicit

Sub IdentifyMatches()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    Dim dataArea As Range
    Set dataArea = ws.Range("A1:F6")

    Dim items As Dictionary
    Set items = New Dictionary

    '--- build the data set of all unique items, and make a note
    '    of which row the item appears.
    '      KEY   = cell value
    '      VALUE = CSV list of row numbers
    Dim rowList As String
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In dataArea.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If items.Exists(cell.Value) Then
                '--- add this row to the list
                rowList = items(cell.Value) & "," & cell.Row
                items(cell.Value) = rowList
            Else
                '--- first time adding this value
                items.Add cell.Value, cell.Row
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    '--- now work through the data, row by row and make the report
    Dim report As String
    Dim duplicateCount As Variant
    ReDim duplicateCount(1 To dataArea.Rows.Count)

    Dim dataRow As Range
    For Each dataRow In dataArea.Rows
        Erase duplicateCount
        ReDim duplicateCount(1 To dataArea.Rows.Count)

        Dim rowNumber As Variant
        For Each cell In dataRow.Cells
            If items.Exists(cell.Value) Then
                rowList = items(cell.Value)
                Dim rowNumbers As Variant
                rowNumbers = Split(rowList, ",")
                For Each rowNumber In rowNumbers
                    If rowNumber <> cell.Row Then
                        duplicateCount(rowNumber) = duplicateCount(rowNumber) + 1
                    End If
                Next rowNumber
            End If
        Next cell

        report = vbNullString
        For rowNumber = 1 To UBound(duplicateCount)
            If duplicateCount(rowNumber) > 0 Then
                report = report & rowNumber & "(" & duplicateCount(rowNumber) & ")" & ", "
            End If
        Next rowNumber
        '--- display the report in the next column at the end of the data area
        If Len(report) > 0 Then
            report = Left$(report, Len(report) - 2) 'removes the trailing comma and space
            dataRow.Cells(1, dataRow.Columns.Count + 1).Value = report
        End If
    Next dataRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @PeterT! I will definitely use the information you have provided. If is not evident, I am clearly a noob with excel VBA.